# Angular $resource, lose scope variable after function call

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

```
 var createAttendances = function(){
    var stud = StudentResource.get(function(data){
        $scope.students = data.students;
        console.log($scope.students);
    });
    console.log(stud.students);
    console.log($scope.sudents);
};
```

inside resource get function it prints out Array of two objects (which is good)
outside resource get it prints out **undefined**

it sees stud object but when i query to students params it returns **undefined**

as u can see main problem is to get $scope.students or data.students **ouside** StudentResouce.get func

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
StudentResource.get
```

is an async call, which means the lines below it can get executed even before the Resource GET call is completed, that is the reason why your variables are returning undefined outside the callback.

to access the data you fetched through GET call, you have to query it inside the call back itself.

Comment: var stud = StudentResource.get(function(data){
           return data.students;
}); but i cannot query students property

Comment: it returns Resource {$promise: Promise, $resolved: false} but cannot query students param

Answer (score 0):

This is an async call, so you can get result in this way, I got the same confusion in the beginning too.

```
StudentResource.get().$promise.then(function (result) {
       $scope.students = result.students;
        console.log($scope.students);
})
```

Comment: do a console.log('result: ' + JSON.stringify(result)); to check the result object